# Directives not loading in order when navigating between pages that reuse directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller, angular-template

I have a two separate pages that use the same controller.
I'm using ui router states to change between pages.
They contain the following directives which use templateUrl for templates in order:
Page A
directive_1
directive_2

Page B
directive_1
directive_3
directive_4
directive_2

Each directive has an array $scope.array that is two way bound to its parent scope $scope.array, and each adds its directive number to that array.
Each directive also console logs 'Here:' + directive number.

I've set up a watch function that watches $scope.array on the common controller and print out $scope.array when anything inside changes

Now when I navigate to Page A, I see in the console
Here: 1
[1]
Here: 2
[1,2]

when I navigate away and then page to Page A, I see in the console
Here: 1
Here: 2
[1,2]

so the watch function only fires once.

Then the strange thing happens, when I got to page B, I see in the console 
Here: 1
Here: 2
[1,2]
Here: 3
[1,2,3]
Here: 4
[1,2,3,4]

So the directives seem like they're not loaded in order! Intuitively, the final order would be
1,3,4,2, like how the directives are laid out on the page.

Is Angular doing a smart compare between templates and concluding that some directives have been loaded already and executing those instantly before attempting the new directives?

When we navigate back to page B the second time, things load normally. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

I think I know why this is. 
Because angular $templateCache is caching as it goes, the first two directives are cached after Page A loads.

When we go to Page B, the cached templates load much faster, so 1 and 2 loads immediately and 3, 4 get loaded and put into the $templateCache.

Next time when we go to Page B, everything is in $templateCache and they load in order again.

In production we put everything in template cache first, so this wouldn't be a problem. 
Otherwise it is extremely tricky if you care about the order of your directives.

Comment: Yeah, a directive with `templateUrl:` and the template isn't ready in the cache yet, will get compiled asynchronously.

Comment: yep, definitely the answer.  console log results can be misleading when dealing with async calls.